# JSON from php to js

Tags: javascript, php, json, parsing

What is the best way to parse a php-variable with json data to js?
On the php-site I have the following:

```
  $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'homedbuser', 'homedbuser');
    $sqlQuery ="SELECT `serie`, `abtrag` FROM `testem`";

    $q = $pdo->query($sqlQuery);

    $result = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $rowcount = $q->rowCount();

    $data = array(); 

    for($x=0; $x < $rowcount-1;$x++){

    $data[]  = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $myJson = json_encode($data);

    echo $myJson;

The Output looks like this:

  [
  {"serie":"KK718X","abtrag":"71"},
  {"serie":"KK712X","abtrag":"337"},
  {"serie":"LK719X","abtrag":"93"},
  {"serie":"KK790Y","abtrag":"78"}
 ]
```

Now I want to put the data into a js-variable.

What kind of variable do I have to choose ?
I tried it with axaj / xmlhttp request but that did not work for jet.
Can some one tell, how to do this the right way?

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = "myObject[1].serie";
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "demo_file_array.php", true);
xmlhttp.send();``
```

Answer (score 0):

with jQuery you can use the following syntax:

```
$.get(url, function(data) { your code; }, 'json');
```

You will automatically get an javascript conform array in the data variable.

Grtngs
Dustin

Comment: Although not a good explanation, he is right, OP said it is outputing a JS Array so data would be said array.

Answer (score 0):

In the following you are using a `literal` string and not a reference to an object `identifier`

```
document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = "myObject[1].serie"
```

Maybe change that to

```
document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = myObj[1].serie;
```

Comment: He has `var myObj` not myObject.

Comment: you should console.log the result of your `JSON.parse(this.responseText)` to verify the json is there and valid, and verify that your property names are correctly spelled.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code snippet you can use for your `XMLHttpRequest`'s success handler:

```
var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = myObj[1].serie;  // Use myObj not myObject and that too without `""`
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following code :

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        //document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = "myObject[1].serie" add a text node to element html.

        document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = myObj[1].serie; //For Obhect data serie.
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "demo_file_array.php", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```